# "This submission failed with error code(s) 2001" when upploading app to Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-10

I try to upload my Windows Phone 8.1 app updated package (.appxupload) to the Windows Store and it tells me
"This submission failed with error code(s) 2001. More info about the error(s) can be found here." with a reference to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/resolve-submission-errors

I can sucessfully build and deploy my app with Visual Studio in both release and debug mode, and also pass the certification, but the Store stops me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem. The problem was finally solved by the following steps:

1. Clean the project
2. Rebuild the project
3. Upload ***.appxupload** manually via website from **YOUR_APP/AppPackages** instead of **.appx** from **bin/ARM/Master**

Hope this will help. If not, there is a similar topic on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/46f39686-9c7c-4d83-908f-0bb97d80c420/error-2001-no-additional-info-given?forum=wpsubmit).